# What does the option `-N` mean in `pcregrep`? Please list some examples

Tags: regex

What does the option `-N` mean in `pcregrep`?

I can't understand the manual.

```
   -N newline-type, --newline=newline-type
             The  PCRE  library  supports  five different conventions for
             indicating the ends of lines. They are the  single-character
             sequences  CR  (carriage return) and LF (linefeed), the two-
             character sequence CRLF, an "anycrlf" convention, which rec‐
             ognizes  any of the preceding three types, and an "any" con‐
             vention, in  which  any  Unicode  line  ending  sequence  is
             assumed  to  end a line. The Unicode sequences are the three
             just mentioned, plus VT (vertical tab,  U+000B),  FF  (form‐
             feed,  U+000C), NEL (next line, U+0085), LS (line separator,
             U+2028), and PS (paragraph separator, U+2029).

             When the  PCRE  library  is  built,  a  default  line-ending
             sequence  is  specified.   This  is  normally  the  standard
             sequence for the operating system. Unless  otherwise  speci‐
             fied  by  this  option, pcregrep uses the library's default.
             The possible values for this option are CR, LF,  CRLF,  ANY‐
             CRLF,  or  ANY.  This  makes  it possible to use pcregrep on
             files that have come from other environments without  having
             to  modify  their  line  endings.  If the data that is being
             scanned does not agree  with  the  convention  set  by  this
             option, pcregrep may behave in strange ways.
```

And I've searched in both Google and stackoverflow, but I can't see any examples.

---

How to use this option? Please see my example below. The `-N` just doesn't work.

```
$ cat /tmp/pcregrep-test
abcd
something1
something2
djfkhh

hh

$ pcregrep -Mo "abcd(.|\n)+k" /tmp/pcregrep-test
abcd
something1
something2
djfk

$ pcregrep -N ANY -Mo "abcd.+k" /tmp/pcregrep-test

$ pcregrep -N any -Mo "abcd.+k" /tmp/pcregrep-test

$ pcregrep --newline=ANY -Mo "abcd.+k" /tmp/pcregrep-test 

$ pcregrep --newline=any -Mo "abcd.+k" /tmp/pcregrep-test

$
```

---

### Answer

**Key Concept**

1. `\n` is always the delimiter of `.*`, that is, `.` never includes `\n`.
2. The option `-N` is to define what `\n` is. What `-N` specifies, is the dilimiter of `.*`.

**Examples** (Original version from Lorehead)

```
$ echo -e "foo\012foo\015bar\012foo baz" > pcretest.txt

$ vim pcretest.txt
foo
foo^Mbar
foo baz 

$ pcregrep -N LF -Mon "^foo.*$" pcretest.txt > result_LF 

$ vim result_LF
1:foo
2:foo^Mbar
3:foo baz
# LF as the newline, the delimiter. Three matches.

$ pcregrep -N CR -Mon "^foo.*$" pcretest.txt > result_CR

$ vim result_CR
1:foo
foo
# CR as the newline, the delimiter. One match.
```

Comment: It works.  You just need to give it the right test cases.  See my expanded answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I see what you’re asking below.  The option does work, and I’ll leave my original post as a historical explanation.

```
$ echo -e "foo\012foo\015bar\012foo baz" > pcretest.txt 
$ more pcretest.txt
foo
bar
foo baz
$ pcregrep -N LF -Mo "^foo.*$" pcretest.txtfoo
foo
bar
foo baz
$ pcregrep -N CR -Mo "^foo.*$" pcretest.txt
foo
foo
$ pcregrep -N ANY -Mo "^foo.*$" pcretest.txt
foo
foo
foo baz
```

**What just happened:**

ASCII character `10`, or octal `\012`, is `LF`.  ASCII character `13`, or octal `\015`, is `CR`.  On the Unix terminal, `LF` means start a new line, while `CR` means go back to the beginning of the line and overwrite anything that was there before.

So, we wrote out `foo LF foo CR bar LF foo baz`.  When we echo these raw codes to the terminal, it interprets them as: foo, new line, foo, erase this line and start over, bar, new line, foo baz.

When we treat `LF` as the end of a line, and `CR` as matching `.*`, we get three lines, `foo`, `foo CR bar`, and `foo baz`.  All of them match the pattern, but when the terminal tries to display the second line, the `CR` tells it to overwrite `foo` with `bar`, so it seems to be telling us that `bar` matches the pattern `^foo.*$`.  Really, though, something just got lost in translation.

When we instead treat `CR` as the end of the line, and `LF` as matching `.*`, we have two lines, `foo LF foo` and `bar LF foo baz`, of which the first one matches the pattern.  But when the Unix terminal tries to display this, it splits the line into two at `LF`.

When we treat either `CR` or `LF` as the end of a line, there are four lines, `foo`, `foo`, `bar` and `foo baz`, of which the third does not match the pattern.

**Why PCRE Does this:**

If you’re reading a file created on Windows (or MS-DOS), lines, like the two between paragraphs here, probably end with the ASCII characters `CR LF` (`10 13`).  If you’re reading a file created on Unix, lines probably end with just `LF` (`10`).  If you’re reading a file created on an old Apple, lines probably end with `CR` (`13`).  The ISO decided to, ahem, help, by introducing its own new way to end a line in ISO-8859-1 that nobody uses, and then the Unicode consortium did the same thing.

The historical reason for this is that some old manual teletype machines had separate commands to advance the roll of paper by one line (line feed) and to move the print head back to the start of the line (carriage return).  Then both MIT and Apple realized that, on a computer, they only needed one.

PCRE wants to have the option to understand any of those formats.  Some terminal scripts actually do use `CR` to move the cursor to the leftmost position of the current line, for example to update a text progress bar, so you might want to search those for the `CR` codes.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation and example. That made me finally understand the logic of `-N`.

BTW, in the `-N LF` example, there's a typo. There should be a newline in the middle of `pcretest.txtfoo`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also find the paragraphs above in the [documentation of PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/original/pcre.txt), under `NEWLINES` heading. The documentation further explains how this flag affects the interpretation of the regex:

> In the PCRE documentation the word "newline" is used to mean "the character or pair of characters that indicate a line break". The choice of newline convention affects the handling of the dot, circumflex, and dollar metacharacters, the handling of #-comments in `/x`mode, and, when CRLF is a recognized line ending sequence, the match position advancement for a non-anchored pattern. [...]

To explain each of the items in the documentation:

- In the default mode, the definition of `.` excludes "newline" characters. The exact list of character depends on this option.

  - If you choose CR, then `.` is equivalent to `[^\r]`.
  - If you choose LF, then `.` is equivalent to `[^\n]`.
  - If you choose CRLF, then `.` is equivalent to `(?:[^\r\n]|\r(?!\n)|(?<!\r)\n)`
  - If you choose ANY-CRLF, then `.` is equivalent to `[^\r\n]`
  - If you choose ANY, then `.` is equivalent to `[^\r\n\v\f\x85\u2028\u2029]`, except for default mode 8-bit library where it is equivalent to `[^\r\n\v\f\x85]` (since one code unit is only 8-bit for 8-bit library).

  Sample runs:

  ```
  $ echo -e 'abc\ndef\rlksdf\r\nsdf' | pcregrep -N CR -Mo 'abc.*'
  abc
  def

  $ echo -e 'abc\ndef\rlksdf\r\nsdf' | pcregrep -N CRLF -Mo 'abc.*'
  abc
  lksdf

  $ echo -e 'abc\ndef\rlksdf\r\nsdf' | pcregrep -N LF -Mo 'abc.*'
  abc
  ```

  (`def` disappears in the second run, since it's overwritten by `\rlksdf` sequence.)
- In multiline mode, `^` and `$` is defined based on the definition of new line character. In default mode, since `$` can match before the terminating newline, the setting also affects what `$` can match.

  - If you choose ANY-CRLF or ANY, which include CR, LR and also CRLF, `^` and `$` will not match in between CRLF sequence.

    <sup>This is also what the documentation means by *The choice of newline convention affects the handling of [...] when CRLF is a recognized line ending sequence, the match position advancement for a non-anchored pattern*. Given `^` with multiline mode and newline mode ANY-CRLF or ANY, it will not match in between CRLF, but instead skips over to after LF in CRLF. `^` with multiline mode is considered non-anchored pattern, since it doesn't restrict the match to beginning of the string (See `PCRE_INFO_FIRSTCHARACTERFLAGS`).</sup>
- In free spacing mode `/x`, we can write single-line comment which starts with `#` and ends at newline. The newline setting affects where the comment ends.

Comment: Hi, please see my edit. I've tried utilizing the option, but it doesn't work. Can you point out what I did wrong? Or can you list out some examples of `pcregrep` using `-N` options?

Comment: @JennyaChang: For your use case, I guess you want `(?s)` to make `.` matches everything, including new line.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your explanation. But I got things clearer by Lorehead's example. Therefore I chose him as the best answer.

If you don't mind, I still want to ask: what's the meaning of `(?s)` in your last comment? Excuse me for that I'm not a veteran in regex.

Comment: @JennyaChang It's inline flag to make `.` matches any character, without exception.